# If $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $p \nmid a^2+3b^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that $a, b$ are co-prime numbers and $p$ is a prime number in the form $4k+1$. Can $3a^2+b^2$ have a prime divisor like $p$?

I really don't know how to think about this! Please help!

Comment: If $a=1,b=2$ then $a^2+3b^2=13$ and $13\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $$a^2\equiv -3b^2\pmod p$$

Now, since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ we can exclude the case where one, hence both, of $a,b$ are divisible by $p$.  Thus we can divide by $b^2$ to see that $-3$ must be a square $\pmod p$.

Assume that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Quadratic reciprocity then tells us that $-3$ is a square $\pmod p$ if and only if $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$.  Thus we require $p\equiv 1 \pmod {12}$.

It is easy to work backwards.  That is, given $a$ such that $a^2\equiv -3 \pmod p$ then $a^2+3\times 1^2$ is divisible by $p$.

Conclusion:  if $p\equiv 1 \pmod {12}$ then we can find coprime $a,b$ with $a^2+3b^2\equiv 1 \pmod {p}$.

Worth noting:  the same technique can applied to the case $p\equiv -1 \pmod 4$.  Again we require that $=3$ be a square $\pmod p$ but again reciprocity forces us to require that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$  Thus we are lead to considering $p\equiv 7 \pmod {12}$

Conclusion:  if an odd prime $p$ divides $a^2+3b^2$ with coprime $a,b$ then $p\equiv 1,7\pmod {12}$.  Conversely, any such prime divides an expression of the desired form.

Comment: Nice answer! It using a lot of theory (quadratic reciprocity is hard...).

Comment: @E.Joseph  Agreed.  But that's really the heart of the matter here.

Comment: When you divide by $b^2$ in the 4th line, then we get $a^2/b^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{p}$. How do you say that $-3$ is a square mod $p$?

Comment: @Deda  In your equation, you have written a square root of $-3$, namely $\frac ab$.  Maybe it would be clearer if you wrote it differently.  Let $c=b^{-1}$ be defined as the solution to $bc\equiv 1 \pmod p$.  Then instead of $\frac ab$ we have $(ac)^2\equiv -3 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that a square is always equal to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$.

So $a^2\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$ and $3b^2\equiv 0,-1\pmod 4$.

So $a^2+3b^2\equiv 0,1,-1\pmod 4$.

So yes, $a^2+3b^2$ has a divisor of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: if $a=4,b=1$ then $a^2+3b^2=19$ which has no divisor of the form $4k+1$ (unless you are counting $1$).

Comment: Lulu, the question asks if $a^2+3b^2$ can have a divisor in the form $p=4k+1$. So, it isn't **compulsory** to have a prime divisor of that form.

Comment: @knm I don't see how that follows from what is written here.

Comment: I edited my comment while you were writing your answer.

Comment: @kmm I don't understand your point.  I understand what the OP is asking...I see no way the solution here is responsive to the question.

Comment: @lulu I think I agree with you. Though I don't think I understand what is the question anymore. Maybe OP can clarify us on that?

Comment: The OP is asking if it is possible for a prime of the form $4k+1$ to divide an expression of the desired type.  The answer is:  yes, provided the prime is also of the form $3m+1$.

Comment: I don't understand the question too, but I think it means that if a number of the form $3a^2+b^2$ can have a prime divisor of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: Whatever the question is, it is not addressed by this answer.